# Format date with "/" to "-" with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have this Javascript function that takes X number of days and returns a date in the past

```
 var GetDateInThePastFromDays = function (days) {

        var today = new Date();
        _date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - days);

        return _date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
```

That works absolutely fine, but it returns the date as `06/01/2016` but I want it returned as `06-01-2016` but I can't seem to find out how to do it correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: you got 660 rep points but didn't think to google "format javascript date" ??????

Comment: use like this,

    var today = new Date();
    alert((today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + '-' +  today.getFullYear());

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toLocaleDateString()` returns a string formatted according to the user's locale, meaning the format will match whatever is set on the user's machine. For me, that's `06/01/2016` but for an American it might be `01/06/2016` (because they're weird like that).

You should define your own format if you want a fixed one:

```
function pad(n) {return (n<10 ? "0" : "")+n;}
return pad(_date.getDate()) + "-" + pad(_date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + _date.getFullYear();
```